# What frame does my mountain bike have?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

I'm trying to work out what my frame is, and what size bottom bracket it needs (68/71/73 mm), and the recommended spindle length. I've attempted to measure both and it *seems* to have a 68/115 bottom bracket.

I can't find any serial number on the frame, but someone told me, circa 2002 that it *looked like* a Marin.

Complete bike

[image: Complete bike]

Yoke

[image: Yoke]

Rear

[image: Rear]

Rear wheel hub, note the unusual markings

[image: Rear wheel]

Rear from top

[image: Rear from top]

Crank

[image: Crank]

Comment: I've seen many frames that look very similar to this. The rear dropout is distinctive but I don't recognize it. The parts may not provide a clue either. The frame is set up for cable pull brakes but you currently have and old Magura hydraulic rim brake. In the absence of frame identification disassembling what you have will provide measurements.

Comment: Do you really need to know what the frame is, or just the BB spec? Shell with is very easy to measure, threads are almost certainly BSA/English. Can you measure the spindle length of the current BB cartridge?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - Roughly seems to be 115 mm, I'll take the arms off and measure it more precisely tomorrow. The BB shell seem to be 68 mm. I was hoping that the threads would be metric, if not, then I'll need to be more specific on eBay. The other threads on the frame seem to metric, for the brakes for example. So wouldn't that mean that the BB threads would be metric as well?

Comment: No, the vast majority of bikes with threaded BB shells use what is colloquially called 'English', although it's actually standardized by ISO. The spec is in inches though:  1.375" x 24 threads per inch. See [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bottombrackets.html) Interesting that you have a loose bearing BB. I'd replace it with a cartridge type. The other thing you'll need to consider is if you have JIS or ISO square tapers see [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/bbtaper.html)

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - I was thinking of buying a BB-UN72. My current BB is loose bearings? Can you tell that from the photos? I hadn't realised, I assumed that it was a cartridge, I've never needed to look at the BB, until now, as the bearings seem to be shot.

Comment: The lockrings on the outside show it’s not a cartridge type. Both cartridge and loose bearing type fit in the English thread shell though

Comment: Take it to a bike shop. They'll be able to identify the bottom bracket by looking at the one you have.

Comment: 100% go for a cartridge BB unit - they are far superior to cup and cone.  Also, its a nice bike, worth maintaining and caring-for.   Might look for some Magura horseshoes to help reinforce the brake posts would be my only suggestion. -- they're an optional part.

Comment: @Criggie - Thanks, I wasn't even aware that I was missing the horseshoes! They would be very useful in protecting the hydraulic pipe, as it *is* rather exposed. Looking on eBay now.

Comment: Tough crowd around here, pictures of bike from loads of different angles, and yet still somehow attracted a down vote.
+1 from me at least for being one of the best written 'ID my bike' type questions i've seen

Answer (score 4):

You  probably will waste more time trying to identify the bike compared to just replacing the BB.

Two options - Easy but likely more expensive - take the to a bike shop have them supply a BB of the correct size, if they supply the wrong size, they should be prepared to swap it.

Or buy one cheap off the internet (probably 68x115) and if its the wrong size, well you have a spare the wrong size for you current bike.

Its unlikely a spindle length of a couple of millimeters too short or long (i.e. one size up or down) will make a major difference. The worst happens is the front derailleur rubs when cross chaining. BB are cheap - $10 for a cheapy, $20 will get a reasonable quality one for that bike. So it won't break the bank if you buy the wrong size first time.